# Running a Silverlight app in C# WebBrowser, how to capture any mouse/keyboard event taking place on the former?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm writing a C# application using WebBrowser to render some webpages. In these webpages, there are .xap SilverLight plugins.

Now I want to capture the mouse and keyboard events on the Silverlight plugin, and handle them in the C# application.

I tried and It seems the Events taking places in Silverlight dosen't trigger WebBrowser's listener.

Is there any way about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [the HTML Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645085(v=vs.95).aspx#ScriptEventHandler)

You will have to annotate the events you want to pass on from Silverlight to Html:

```
[ScriptableMemberAttribute]
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
```

and then register an object that will be available in the Html of the page:

```
MyStockWatcher m = new MyStockWatcher();
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("stockwatcher", m);
```

`stockwatcher` will be available in javascript on the page.

Passing this on to the C# applications by using the answer to this question:
[How to detect javascript execution in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567715/how-to-detect-javascript-execution-in-webbrowser-control)

Pass the event to C# by accessing `window.external` in the java script.

Comment: Thanks. But the Silverlight app is compiled by others. I don't have its source code thus can't add any annotate onto it. 

Is there still any hope in this situation?

Comment: At most you could detect global mouse events but you wouldn't have knowledge about what has been clicked on unless you add a lot of data/information to your application (locations of buttons, state, ....)

Comment: That could be a last resort. Thanks for your reply.